# Как изменить формат даты в SQLite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite, дата, datetime, sqlite3

У меня есть таблица с числами:

```
15/10/2016
3/03/2016
4/05/2016
```

Я хочу применить оператор `between`, но у меня не получается. Я пытался применить функцию `strftime()`

```
SELECT date, strftime('%Y', date) as year
```

Результат - NULL.

Полный запрос:

```
SELECT name, s_name, date, avg(price)
FROM supp_order
WHERE name = 'Ivan' and s_name = 'Ivanovich'
    and date_duties between '4/05/2016' and '15/10/2016'
```

Проблема с форматом даты. Как это изменить?

Comment: весь запрос покажите

Comment: да зачем в комментарий-то, в вопрос добавьте

Comment: добавьте так же вариант с between

Comment: не понятно, что нужно получить и на каких условиях

Comment: Я хочу найти среднее число, у меня проблема только с датой, я хочу поменять формат

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В SQLite отсутствует полноценная поддержка Date-Time типов, соответственно вам придется воспользоваться одним из предлагаемых ниже вариантов...

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> **TEXT** as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
>
> **REAL** as Julian
>   day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
>   24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
>
> **INTEGER** as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>   Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.
>
> **Time Strings**
>
> A time string can be in any of the following formats:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
now
DDDDDDDDDD
```

Пример:

```
sqlite> create table test(dt timestamp);
sqlite> insert into test values('2016-11-29');
sqlite> insert into test values('2016-10-01');
sqlite> insert into test values('2016-12-01');
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> select * from test;
dt
----------
2016-11-29
2016-10-01
2016-12-01
sqlite> select * from test where dt between '2016-11-01' and '2016-11-30';
dt
----------
2016-11-29
```

Comment: Так получается, что мне надо изменить тип данных в столбце?

Comment: @maxim, да, я привел пример в ответе

Comment: А нельзя как нибуть изменит это на наш формат 29/11/2016 к примеру?

Comment: @maxim, можно, но тогда это будет строка и сравнение работать не будет ;-)

Comment: Ок спасибо за ответ.